# How to make a request from foursquare with unity3d WWW

Tags: c#, web, unity-game-engine, foursquare

first of all, is it possible? i think it is with the new unity 5.
i want to make a request from foursquare with WWW.

- WWW : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html
- Foursquare : https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks easy. You have an example of a `GET` request on the link you provided:

*https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=sushi*

Let's translate this into code:

```
string CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";
string CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET";
string v = "20130815";
string ll = "40.7,-74";
string query = "sushi";

string url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?";
url += "client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&";
url += "CLIENT_SECRET=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&";
url += "v=" + v + "&";
url += "ll=" + ll + "&";
url += "query=" + query;
```

Now, send to Server:

```
WWW connection = new WWW(url);
yield return connection;

if (connection.error != null)
{
    Debug.Log("Server-side error: " + connection.error);

}
else
{
    Debug.Log(connection.text);
}
```

*You must replace `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` with your own values.*